# How can I get my SSRS Data sources/Data sets to run in parallel?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm having issues with my SSRS reports running slow. Using SQL Profiler, I found out that the queries are running one at a time. I did research and found the suggestion to make sure "Use single transaction when processing the queries" was not clicked in my Data Source. This was already set to off. I am now testing if not only the Data sets won't run in parallel, but the Data Sources also won't run in parallel.

Using SQL Profiler, I'm finding that my single .Net Client Process logs into the first Data Source, sets up properties..

```
SELECT 
DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation'),
COLLATIONPROPERTY(CONVERT(char, DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'collation')),'LCID')
```

and then runs my SQL statement. After completion, the same ClientProcessID moves onto the next Data Source and does that one.

Has anyone run into this problem before? Are there other issues at play?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any report and query parameters?

Comment: I usually do, but for testing I stripped it down pretty basic. One DataSet is a Select top 100 * from TableA and the other is a Select top 100 * from TableB.

Comment: Are you running/testing these on the reporting server, or from your development machine? Because, the dataset queries will not run in parallel in BIDS, but they should on the server.

Comment: That's exactly it. I was testing in BIDS. If I run profiler on a  deployed version, the queries all start at the same time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running/testing these on the reporting server, or from your development machine? Because, the dataset queries will not run in parallel in BIDS, but they should on the server. (Posted in comments by R. Richards)